# Findbugs showing "BIT_ADD_OF_SIGNED_BYTE" bug

Tags: java, findbugs

I have written the following code but findbugs is shwowing this error: `BIT_ADD_OF_SIGNED_BYTE`. I tried a lot but may be I am not getting the concept of left shift correctly.

```
void problem() {
    byte [] byteArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int localOne = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        localOne = (localOne<<8) + byteArray[i]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read [the description of that warning](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'r doing the shift correctly, your (possible) error is when adding a signed `byte` to an `int`

Because of sign extension you need to do this:

```
localOne = (localOne<<8) + (0xFF & byteArray[i]);
```

Say you have the byte `80` (hex), which is `1000 0000` (binary), this is `-128` (decimal) because of the two's complement representation. Now, when adding it to an `int` it first gets converted to an `int`. The resulting `int` is **not**

```
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  1000 0000
```

(binary) it will be

```
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1000 0000
```

(binary) because of sign extension. To get the first, you have to apply a bitwise and with `0xFF` wich is this in binary:

```
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  1111 1111
```

Comment: Hi jlordo : i have done this it worked but could you plz explain how this works?